# Limit of product with prime numbers

Tags: calculus, infinite-product

A friend found a calculus problem in an old box with a lot of math exercises, but we don't have the answer to one of them. If you could help us with a *hint* it would be nice! The question is:  what is the limit of the following infinite product?

$$
\prod_{p \in \mathbb{P}} \frac{p^4+1}{p^4-1}
$$

Here $\mathbb{P}$ is the set of prime numbers.

Comment: What do you want to know about this product?

Comment: @RobArthan The answer maybe... but we want to try to do this product before some of you give us the answer else there is no challenge... :D

Comment: Well... knowing the answer doesn't negate the challenge of proving that it is correct. It's pretty easy to guess what it must be, just by calculating it for the first couple of dozen primes in Excel...

Comment: I'm wondering if you can use $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^s} = \prod_{p \in \Bbb{P}}\frac{p^s}{p^s-1}$$ somehow

Comment: After numerical calculations with PARI/GP, I conjecture $\frac{7}{6}$.

Comment: How much have you worked with Reimann's zeta function?

Comment: @graydad I'm just thinking about but I have to sleep (la nuit porte conseil) sorry i'm french and i have a very bad english :P

Comment: I never saw the mentioned relation with the zeta function. Alas, it is not quite what we are looking for, but really close.

Comment: You take the old box and place it in a lake. If it floats, it's a witch.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20259/discussion-between-shadock-and-rob-arthan).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**Hint:** Using **Gray Dad**'s [suggestion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function), along with the fact that $p^4+1=\dfrac{p^8-1}{p^4-1}$ , one should easily arrive at the conclusion that $P=\dfrac{\zeta^2(4)}{\zeta(8)}=\dfrac76$ , thus confirming **Peter**'s numerical result.

Comment: How do you compute the ratio of the powers of zeta functions?

Comment: @user2566092 the values of Zeta functions at even numbers are known explicitly; $\zeta(2n)$ is always a rational multiple of $\pi^{2n}$.

Comment: Ah, there it is. Nicely done!

Answer (score 5):

More generally:

Let
$R_n
=\prod_{p \in \mathbb{P}} \frac{p^n+1}{p^n-1}
$.

Since
$\zeta(s)
=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^s} = \prod_{p \in \Bbb{P}}\frac{p^s}{p^s-1}
$
and
$p^n+1
=\frac{p^{2n}-1}{p^n-1}
$,

$\begin{array}\\
R_n
&=\prod_{p \in \mathbb{P}} \frac{\frac{p^{2n}-1}{p^n-1}}{p^n-1}\\
&=\prod_{p \in \mathbb{P}} \frac{p^{2n}-1}{(p^n-1)^2}\\
&=\prod_{p \in \mathbb{P}} \frac{p^{2n}-1}{p^{2n}}\frac{p^{2n}}{(p^n-1)^2}\\
&=\prod_{p \in \mathbb{P}} \frac{p^{2n}-1}{p^{2n}}\prod_{p \in \mathbb{P}}\frac{p^{2n}}{(p^n-1)^2}\\
&=\frac1{\zeta(2n)}\left(\prod_{p \in \mathbb{P}}\frac{p^{n}}{p^n-1}\right)^2\\
&=\frac{\zeta^2(n)}{\zeta(2n)}\\
\end{array}
$

For even integer $n$,
this is a rational number,
but
$R_n =\frac{\zeta^2(n)}{\zeta(2n)}$
 is also true
for real $n > 1$.